# No se puede colocar el texto del pie de página en la misma línea que el número de página con html-to-docx

Tags: javascript, html, npm, docx, footer

Estoy tratando de generar un pie de página con la libreria html-to-docx y quiero poner el numero de página en la misma linea que el resto del contenido del footer, pero hace un salto de linea, es decir, se pone el numero y en la siguiente linea lo demás. ¿Alguien me podria ayudar?
Entiendo que para mostrar el numero de pagina, la libreria reconoce el espacio para este, que es el string de "no_pagina".

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gjoKP.png)  Es un ejemplo de como sale el pie de pagina al momento de descargar el documento. Gracias!

```
var headerHTMLString = event.encabezado;
var footerHTMLString = '';

var footerContent = event.pie_pagina;
var mostrarFooter = false;
var num_pagina = false;

if(event.num_pagina == 1){
  num_pagina = true;
  mostrarFooter = true;
}

if(footerContent !==""){
  footerHTMLString = '<div style="font-size: 7px; display: flex; justify-content: space-between;">';
  if (event.num_pagina == 1) {
    var no_pagina = '<span style="text-align: right; flex: 1;display: inline-block;"></span>';
    footerHTMLString = footerHTMLString + no_pagina + footerContent;
  }
  else{
    footerHTMLString = footerHTMLString + footerContent;
  }
  
  footerHTMLString = footerHTMLString + '</div>';
  mostrarFooter = true;
}

const fileBuffer = await HTMLtoDOCX(htmlString, headerHTMLString, {
table: { row: { cantSplit: true } },
footer: mostrarFooter,
header: true,
pageNumber: num_pagina}, footerHTMLString );
```